# Updating a nested vector

Tags: vector, clojure

Let's say i have the following vector

```
(def x [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8]])
```

and I want to append the number 9 to the last vector (I don't know the index of the vector)

```
(conj (vec (butlast x)) (conj (last x) 9))
 #=> [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]]
```

Is there a better/clearer way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the efficient tail access functions

```
(conj (pop x) (conj (peek x) 9))
```

But you could also

```
(update-in x [(dec (count x))] conj 9)
```